# creating stackView inside of view controller crashes with 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors'

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, stackview

I am trying to create a very simple stackView in my viewcontroller. I want the stackView to cover the entire screen. How I am creating the stackView is

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class Vc: UIViewController {
        
var scrollView: UIScrollView {
    let scroll = UIScrollView()
    scroll.isScrollEnabled = true
    return scroll
}

var stackView: UIStackView {
    let stack = UIStackView()
    stack.axis = .vertical
    stack.distribution = .fillEqually
    return stack
    
}
    

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
    self.navigationItem.title = "Profile"
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    addStackViewAnchors()
    
}

func addStackViewAnchors() {
    view.addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.anchors(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, topPad: 0, bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, bottomPad: 0, left: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor, leftPad: 0, right: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor, rightPad: 0, height: .zero, width: .zero)
}

}
```

When I run this, my app crashes and it says

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x283c5e840 "UIStackView:0x135666a90.top"> and <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x283c5e140 "UILayoutGuide:0x28103b8e0'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.top"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'
 terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

There are no conflicting constraints because the stackView is the only anchor being set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you called `stackView` here you `init` a new instance of Stack View from inside your function. That's the reason when you called `stackView.anchor` the error appears because it is autolayout the new instance of `stackView` not the `stackView` you add subview into your `VC`.

The thing you should do is create a variable to store your `stackView` instance so the `stackView` init for once and reuse in all in the `VC`.

Beside of that, we use `leadingAnchor` instead of `leftAnchor`; `trailingAnchor` instead of `rightAnchor`.

Code will be like this

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var stackViewInScreen : UIStackView?
    
    var stackView: UIStackView {
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.distribution = .fillEqually
        return stack
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        addStackViewAnchors()
    }

    func addStackViewAnchors() {
        self.stackViewInScreen = stackView
        self.view.addSubview(self.stackViewInScreen!)
        
        self.stackViewInScreen!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.stackViewInScreen?.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.stackViewInScreen!.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0),
            self.stackViewInScreen!.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
            self.stackViewInScreen!.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
            self.stackViewInScreen!.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
        ])
    }
}
```